# regedit.exe doesn't work from within a Windows 10 ssh session

Tags: windows-10, command-line, openssh, regedit

I am running Windows 10 Pro (ver 1809) OpenSSH.  When I SSH into the Windows 10 box as an administrator, I am unable to run `regedit.exe /S <reg file>`.  Typing in the command just returns me to the command line prompt.  I am able to successfully run the `reg.exe` command; I can query and make changes to the registry with `reg.exe`.  This tells me that I am indeed executing as an admin.  I have verified that 'regedit.exe' invoked in the SSH session does not work by running 'regedit.exe' from the console and using the GUI interface to examine the registry keys that I wanted to change.  The keys are unchanged.

`regedit.exe /S <reg file>` works fine from a console admin command prompt; it just doesn't work from within an SSH session.  Has anyone else seen this behavior?

Comment: you may have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11351283/how-can-i-change-on-windows-a-registry-value-remotely

Comment: I’ve never used ssh in Windows. What happens if you run some other GUI program (e.g., Notepad, WordPad, Calculator, Paint, etc.) from ssh?

Comment: What do you expect `regedit /s` to do in your SSH terminal window?

Comment: @Martin I am operating in a non-domain environment and I would like to make registry changes via an SSh session.  I can make the changes using the 'reg' command but the 'regedit /S' command fails.  'regedit' is much more convenient to use as it takes '*reg' files.

Comment: @Scott When I execute a GUI program (notepad) from within an SSh session nothing happens.  This may be the problem with 'regedit' as it is a GUI program even though invoking it with the '/S' option does not generate any graphical output.

Comment: OK, I just realized (by editing the question) that you were talking about ``regedit /S <reg file>`` the whole time.  Did you not notice that your question was displayed incorrectly?  And you have not given a good answer to [Martin Prikryl’s question](https://superuser.com/q/1434202/150988#comment2164795_1434202): What do you expect to happen?  Or, to put it another way, what do you mean when you say “the 'regedit /S' command fails” and “it just doesn’t work”?  The fact that it “just returns [you] to the command line prompt” without writing any output to the screen  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) … doesn’t mean that it failed: look at `ren file1 file2` and `del file2` — if there’s no error, they write no output.  Are you looking in the registry (e.g., with `reg`) and seeing that the changes from your <reg file> have not been made?  If so, please [edit] your question to say so.

Answer (score 1):

`regedit` is a graphical (GUI) program,
and you aren’t going to be able to run it in an ssh session. 
The `/S` option can be used to suppress pop-up windows
when you’re importing a file; e.g.,

```
regedit /s myfle.reg
```

but it doesn’t give you the normal, interactive behavior of regedit
in a command-line environment.

If you’re running on a Windows computer
(i.e., you’re running the ssh client on a Windows computer)
and you want to edit the registry of a remote machine,
you may be able to do that by running `regedit` on your local machine:
see [How to remotely edit the registry of a client computer
from a host computer …](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/934958/how-to-remotely-edit-the-registry-of-a-client-computer-from-a-host-com) and [other references](https://www.google.com/search?q=remote+regedit).